# The shortest way from num1 to num2 (in C++)

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to write a function (in C++) the gets two integer numbers (>0) (n1,n2).
I can do only two things:

- add 1 to n1.
- multiply n1 by 2.

The function returns the number of steps of the shortest way from n1 to n2.
Can you give me ideas how to do it?

Thank you!

P.S.
If it's impossible the function returns -1.

here What I tried:

```
if (n1<n2)
{
    n1++;
    if ((n1)*2<=n2)
        return 2+f(n1*2,n2);
    else
        return 1+f(n1,n2);
}
```

Comment: Only these two things? What about comparisons? What else are you leaving out?

Comment: I try to put some of the code here, but it's unreadable...

Yes - only those two things...

Comment: Do you need to use recursion?

Comment: Yes...:-) But I tried to find the algorithm first.

Comment: Yoav, put the code, it'll help to better understand your problem. Plus, other users can edit the post and format the code (if you ask nicely) ;)

Comment: Add 1 until n1 is a binary prefix of n2. Then either you have reached n2, or you multiply by 2 and recurse.

Comment: There is problem at your solution: (12,67) will returns 9, but the shortest way is 8 steps...

Comment: (12,67):   12->13->14->15->16->32->**33**->66->67.  You see, I had to add one after 32. And if I multiply 32 by 2 I will get: 64->65->66->67 one step more...

Comment: @YoavFridman we increment n1 until it is a prefix of 67, that is until n1=16. It is not n2, so we multiply by 2: n1=32. Recurse. We increment n1 until it is a prefix of 67: n1=33. It is not n2, so we multiply by 2: n1=66. Increment n1: 67. Done. I have no idea why you went to 64, 32 (100000 in binary) is not a prefix of 67 (1000011).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it is best to turn the problem around: Go from n2 to n1 with these two tings:

- subtract by 1
- divide by 2 (only if result it an integer)

This way you are able to find the biggest steps when you first try to divide the number by 2 and if that is not possible subtract by 1 (after which dividing works). COntinue doing this until your reach n1 (or a lower value, after which you only can use the 'decrease step' and thus basically know the required amount of steps already)

I suppose you can implement this algorithm by yourself...

Comment: Unfortunately I can do only the two tings that I mention above...

Comment: Then the algorithm becomes *much more inefficient*, as you have to brute-force all possible branches from n1 to n2 to find the 'biggest jump' by the multiplications (in order to get the least amount of steps).

Comment: But what you suggest looks very good! Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman are you only allowed to use multiplication by 2 and adding 1, or do you have to find the shortest way to get from n1 to n2 using only multiplication by 2 and adding 1?

Comment: @harold hehe... indeed if the algorithm is allowed to use anything it is still valid, as the result shows how you can use the shortest route using the multiplications and additions. Nice way of looking at the problem!!

Comment: now I need to think how to do it from n1 to n2....

Comment: @harold - Ihave to find the shortest way to get from n1 to n2 using only multiplication by 2 and adding 1, just for n1...

Comment: @YoavFridman ok but it's still not very clear - do you just have to find the right answer, or does it also have to be done in some specific way?

Comment: Well after you used the above algorithm you can go from n1 to n2 in the least amount of steps using only multiplication by 2 and adding 1. (True the algorithm uses other means, but that might not be a problem, it is also requires conditional checks, function calls, and so on)

Comment: @harold - for your question: The function need to return the shortest way from n1 to n2. The function returns the **amount** of the stpes, nothing else :-) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Think about it one step at a time.

Lets say `n1` is `start` and `n2` is `end`.

if you are at `end` already, then you need no steps.
if `start` is greater than `end`, the you cant do it.

Otherwise u have two options..

- Add 1 to `start` and repeat the process recursively - store number of steps as `add`
- Multiply `start` by 2 and repeat the process recursively - store number of steps as `mult`

If both are possible then the lowest of the two is your answer.

If you got my code before it was deleted, I hope you will take the time to step through it, else you can try to write it out.. It takes about a minute or so..

p.s. For large number of steps you might want to implement this as a tail recursive algorithm to prevent a `<insert name of the website here>`.

p.p.s This is a very inefficient algorithm since it explores each branch. You can try to improve it and try to reduce the number of branches needed, perhaps only add if mult wont do..

Comment: I didn't saw the code, but I think it's better... Because, now I have the basic idea and I need to think by **myself** how to solve it. thank you!

Comment: As I wrote to ShingSun this results in the wrong answer: *Take 2 and 6 for example, your algorithm returns 3 (2 * 2 + 1 + 1), while it is 2 ((2 + 1) * 2)*. I suspect the only way is to brute-force try all branches and keep the shortest (if backtracking is not allowed)

Comment: @Veger how do you infer that this returns the wrong answer? This is a rather inefficient recursive function that does indeed explore all branches..

Comment: @Veger - you right, but how can I make algorithm for this?  And Karthik, you have a problem at your code: (12,65) should return 7... But thank you!!!

Comment: @Veger I have tested my code and it DOES return 2.

Comment: @YoavFridman similarly, it DOES return 7. Bloody 15 second timer! Atleast they should have it count down if it resets on a missclick..

Comment: @YoavFridman Perhaps you can put up what you came up with to implement this logic, then I can put up mine in good conscience.

Comment: I checked your previous answer and saw that you are indeed trying all branches. I misunderstood from your current explanation...

Comment: @Veger is my explanation missleading? How can I improve it.

Comment: It was unclear to me that you were branching. Instead of `try again` (in the two bullets) you might say something about store the current amount of steps and rerun the algorithm from this point on (or something.... ;) )

Comment: @Veger Oh i didnt want to make it too obvious :P "try again" was my code for recursive call. A little better now I hope

Comment: I do not think it is 'too obvious' for the OP... :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can transform the problem into a problem that admits greedy choice by going in reverse, from n2 to n1. The answer is, of course, the same.

But some more observations can be made:

- if shifting would result in a number that is too low, the number of steps you must take from now is `current - n1`, you don't have to count all those steps one by one.
- if shifting would result in a number that *isn't* too low, it doesn't matter whether you're currently at an odd or an even number, you can always shift (but add the lowest bit to the number of steps taken, because it would have taken a step)
- using the positions of the highest set bit in n1 and n2, it's possible to do more than one shift at once (add both the shift amount and the hamming weight of the bits that you're shifting out to the number of steps). The number of shifts you can do is `bsr(n2) - bsr(n1) - 1`, but beware of edge cases. This is not always the maximum number of shift steps, it can take one more (but no more than that).

Answer (score 0):

```
int numOfSteps(int n1, int n2) {
    if (n1 > n2) return -1;
    if (n1 == n2) return 0;
    int result = 0;
    while (n1 * 2 <= n2) {
            n1 *= 2;
            result ++;
    }
    while (n1 < n2) {
            n1 ++;
            result ++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is not returning the least amount of steps... Take 2 and 6 for example, your algorithm returns 3 (2 * 2 + 1 + 1), while it is 2 ((2 + 1) * 2)

Comment: I know that is not the right algo. but this why I'm here...

Comment: for (12,65) it's doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I solve it!
(I ask for advises from my friend...)

here is the code:

```
int f(unsigned int n1, unsigned int n2){

int num1,num2;

if (n1==n2)
        return 0;
if (n1>n2)
    return -1;
num1=f(n1+1,n2)+1;
num2=f(n1*2,n2)+1;
return min(num1,num2);}
```

And here is "min":

```
int min (unsigned int n1, unsigned int n2){
if (n1*n2==0) //If one of them is zero then (n1+n2) return the non-zero
              //number.
    return n1+n2;
else
    if (n1>n2)
        return n2;
    else
        return n1;}
```

**Thank you!!**

Comment: f is the function that calculating the number of steps...